# Call an R function against all variables

Tags: r, function

I have to run a function against all variables in a data frame, basically change wind direction in degrees to direction names. I have written a function that works if I give it individual values but not working against whole data frame.

Here is my function:

```
compute_aggregate_wind_dir <- function(wind_dir)  {

                  if(wind_dir >= 0 && wind_dir <= 45) {
                     wind_dir = 'N' } else if(wind_dir > 45 && wind_dir <= 90) {
                     wind_dir = 'NE' } else if(wind_dir > 90 && wind_dir <= 135) {
                     wind_dir = 'E' } else if(wind_dir > 135 && wind_dir <= 180) {
                     wind_dir = 'SE' } else if(wind_dir > 180 && wind_dir <= 225) {
                     wind_dir = 'S' } else if(wind_dir > 225 && wind_dir <= 270) {
                     wind_dir = 'SW' } else if(wind_dir > 270 && wind_dir <= 315) {
                     wind_dir = 'W' } else {
                     wind_dir = 'NW' }

                 wind_dir                 

              }
```

Here is my data frame:

```
wind_direction <- data.frame(
                        wind_dir = c(0,51,95,229,175)
  )
 # Print the data frame.            
 print(wind_direction)
```

Here is how I am calling it to update the direction in data frame:

```
wind_direction = compute_aggregate_wind_dir(wind_dir)
```

Its printing only NW when I print the results.

```
> print(wind_direction) 
  wind_dir
1        0
2       51
3       95
4      229
5      175
> wind_direction = compute_aggregate_wind_dir(wind_dir)
> wind_direction
[1] "NW"
```

What I want to do the whole data frame is updated with the direction names instead of degrees after calling the function-

How to make it working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As these are continuous values I would suggest using `cut` here and give appropriate `labels`

```
compute_aggregate_wind_dir <- function(x) {
   cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, Inf), 
          labels = c("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"))
}

compute_aggregate_wind_dir(wind_direction$wind_dir)
#[1] N  NE E  SW SE
```

and if there are multiple columns which you want to update, you could use `lapply` and update the dataframe.

```
wind_direction[] <- lapply(wind_direction, compute_aggregate_wind_dir)
```

Comment: The early bird gets the worm +1.  What more can I say?

Comment: I used an example data frame here. The original data frame has few thousand entries and those are not continuous as it's real wind direction data. By cont, I understood that they increase in ascending order like you put in the answer.

Comment: @XCeptable maybe continuous is not the right word here but the idea is to divide numbers into buckets. So 1st bucket is from -Inf to 45, second from 45 to 90 and giving labels to those buckets.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your current function is that it is using plain `if` `else` statements, which are not vectorized by default.  While you *could* use base R's `ifelse` function here, which is vectorized, a better approach might be to use `case_when` from the `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)

compute_aggregate_wind_dir <- function(wind_dir)  {
    case_when(
        wind_dir >= 0 && wind_dir <= 45 ~ 'N',
        wind_dir <= 90 ~ 'NE',
        wind_dir <= 135 ~ 'E',
        wind_dir <= 180 ~ 'SE',
        wind_dir <= 225 ~ 'S',
        wind_dir <= 270 ~ 'SW',
        wind_dir <= 315 ~ 'W',
        TRUE ~ 'NW'
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over every value in your dataframe by using a `for`-loop.

The code for this would look like this and prints all the wind directions:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(wind_direction)) {
    print(compute_aggregate_wind_dir(wind_direction[i, ]))
}
```